# How ought I limit Thread creation using Concurrent-Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, concurrent-ruby

I have a process which uses the [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem to handle a large number of API calls concurrently using `Concurrent::Future.execute`, and, after some time, it dies:

```
ERROR -- : can't create Thread (11) (ThreadError)
/current/vendor/bundler_gems/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/concurrent-ruby-cba3702c4e1e/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:280:in `initialize'
```

Is there a simple way I can tell `Concurrent` to limit the number of threads it spawns, given I have no way of knowing in advance just how many API calls it's going to need to make?

Or is this something I need to code for explicitly in my app?

I am using `Ruby 2.0.0` (alas don't currently have the option to change that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some reading and some trial and error I have worked out the following solution. Posting here in case it helps others.

You control the way `Concurrent` uses threads by specifying a [`RubyThreadPoolExecutor`](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/RubyThreadPoolExecutor.html)<sup>1</sup>

So, in my case the code looks like:

```
threadPool = Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor.new(
  min_threads: [2, Concurrent.processor_count].min,
  max_threads: [2, Concurrent.processor_count].max,
  max_queue:   [2, Concurrent.processor_count].max * 5,
  overflow_policy: :caller_runs
)

result_things = massive_list_of_things.map do |thing|
  (Concurrent::Future.new executor: threadPool do
    expensive_api_call using: thing
  end).execute
end
```

So on my laptop I have 4 processors so this way it will use between 2 and 4 threads and allow up to 20 threads in the queue before forcing the execution to use the calling thread. As threads free up the Concurrency library will reallocate them.

Choosing the right multiplier for the `max_queue` value looks like being a matter of trial and error however; but `5` is a reasonable guess.

<sup>1</sup> *The actual docs describe a different way to do this but the actual code disagrees with the docs, so the code I have presented here is based on what actually works.*

Comment: Do let us know if more than 1 processor actually gets used. I'd be keen to find out.

Comment: Looking at ActivityMonitor it's certainly using both physical cores and also pushing work out to the Hyper-Threaded virtual cores, so yes it is. Reliably sitting on 98% of CPU overall with between 10 and 15 actual OS threads running.

Answer (score 0):

The typical answer to this is to create a Thread pool.

Create a finite number of threads, have a way of recording which are active and which aren't. When a thread finishes an API call, mark it as inactive, so the next call can be handled by it.

The gem you're using already has thread pools.

Comment: yeah - jut been pouring through the docs for `Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor`. Very poor documentation but I think I have it worked out.  Will write up my answer once properly tested